# Prevent pop-ups from being blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup

I am using a Facebook login method in my code on page load, but when I execute this code, the pop-up blocker closes the Facebook permission window.

How can I open this window with `Javascript` without needing to make an exception in the pop-up blocker?

Below is my code:

```
FB.login(function(response)
{
    if(response.session!=null)
    {
        window.location.href='http://example.com';
    }
},
{ perms: 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream' });
```

Comment: Anyone have a idea to show facebook permission popup in iframe ,It may be solved popup blocker problem. Have any??

Comment: See possible answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779955/can-you-call-fb-login-inside-a-callback-from-other-fb-methods-like-fb-getlogins/12851737#12851737

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like -

```
var uri = encodeURI('http://example.com');
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
                window.location.href=uri;
      } else {
         window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri="+uri+"&response_type=token");
      }
```

This will just redirect directly instead of opening a pop-up

Comment: interesting, but where do you ask for specific permissions like "{perms:'email,user_birthday,publish_stream'}"?

Comment: In the redirect oauth URI, using an extra GET parameter 'scope'. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Answer (score 15):

This is specifically denied in the documentation:

"You should only call this on a user event as it opens a popup. Most browsers block popups, unless they were initiated from a user event, such as a click on a button or a link."

It's also simply poor UX.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is "simply poor UX."  It's less obtrusive to avoid a popup, _especially_ in the case where the user is _already_ connected to Facebook, where a popup quickly appears and disappears.  I would argue that it's better UX design to redirect for oauth rather than open a popup.

Comment: Nevermind my above comment... what I was saying was with regards to a user-initiated interaction, I hadn't paid attention to the fact that the OP was looking for a way to _clandestinely_ authorize them via Facebook.

Answer (score 6):

There'd be no point in popup blockers existing if you could just code around them. You'll either need to find a method that doesn't use a popup or require some user interaction with the browser to open the popup.

Comment: I don't want to use user interaction, bcoz after click on my invitation link invitee go on my home where i want to showing facebook permission popup without any user interaction.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah you need to call it with a user event, but strictly the `onclick` event, not any other:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fbLogin()"> Login</a> <!-- works -->

<a href="#" onmousedown="fbLogin()"> Login</a> <!-- doesnt work -->

<a href="#" onmouseup="fbLogin()"> Login</a> <!-- doesnt work -->
```

Answer (score 5):

If you try to open a popup automatically then there is a high possibility that popup blockers will become activated, as far as I know, it has to be based on some User action, for example click of a button. Try to execute this code on click of a button, it should work.

Comment: Yes Arnab! It can handle via click event but, i need to show this on page load. Have any idea ???

Comment: Try ```document.getElementById('shareButtonId').click()```