# Facebook login without pop-up?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to make a simple facebook app, but for the authorization, it seems that it's always blocked by a popup-blocker. My code is thus:

```
FB.init({
        appId  : THEAPPPIDDDD,
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            xfbml  : true,
   });


FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               FB.logout(function(response) {
                               console.log('Logged out.');
                           });
                   });
           } else {
               console.log('User did not authorize.');
           }
       });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks

Comment: I think it's impossible to do Facebook login without a pop-up - by design. It would be bad security. To prevent most pop-up blockers from blocking the pop-up you need to make sure the pop-up is as a direct result of a user-click. Pop-ups that aren't user initiated tend to be blocked.

Answer (score 29):

I aware that this question is a possible duplicate of [another question: Stop the facebook popup blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956359/stop-the-facebook-popup-blocker) I am reposting this to help Dave Zhang. I have adapted this code for one of my site. In the following code, replace the YOUR_APP_ID and your website url, then the Facebook login will be popup-less.

```
//Javascript
var uri = encodeURI('http://example.com');
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        window.location.href=uri;
    } else {
        window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri="+uri+"&response_type=token");
    }
});
```

This will just redirect directly instead of opening a pop-up.

Comment: You should always use `top.location.href = 'URI_TO_REDIRECT'` when redirecting inside an iframe in Facebook

Comment: I tried using redirect method, but i am getting the error that my domain is not included in the app. But i have done that.
 See this image http://ibb.co/d8bBrm See the second image where i have declared the app domain - http://ibb.co/erMBrm – Abhay Srivastav 1 hour ago

Comment: if you are not logged in already this will send you to a page saying "Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

Answer (score 3):

You should initiate your login code on click of some button. As a good practice while dealing with FB, the login process should always be initiated by user.

Call your code on click of a button and it should FIX your problem.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid doing the login via a popup, you should kick off the authentication at the server side

Comment: Some apps are only client-side - so using a button avoids the popup issue.

Answer (score 1):

Small update for this old question which I found very useful, I was keep getting error which the domain is not allowed and it was allowed:

**Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**

so, after small research I discovered you have to change your facebook app setting to allow such navigation:

1. enforce HTTPS
2. Use Strict Mode for redirect URIs
3. Embedded Browser OAuth Login (In case you use app webview)
   [image: Settings needs to enable]

Answer (score 0):

The popup blocker will always initiate if the Popup action did not originate in an event caused by a user. For example, if you try and do a popup on a load event, the browser will most likely use the popup blocker. On the other hand, if you trigger the popup on a click event or keydown event, it is less likely that the popup blocker will be triggered.

You could also employ a method that has your application detect whether or not the popup was blocked. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome).

As mentioned in other answers, if you'd rather do the authentication process without popups at all, you would need to handle this at the server side using OAuth.