# Facebook login using javascript sdk without popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the javascript sdk to implement facebook login. Is it possible to redirect the user to the full login page instead of displaying the popup? I tried adding display : 'page' but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
FB.init({

    appId: '123456789',
    cookie: true,
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    oauth: true
});

function login() { //this function called on click of login button
   FB.login(function (response) {
    //my code
   }, { scope: 'email,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access' });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/#step2 The document is called _“Login without Javascript SDK”_, but of course you can still use the SDK for the rest of your app’s logic besides login. (Although you might have to pass the access token for your SDK operations manually each time, because the SDK does not provide a documented method to set the access token.)

Comment: Will the access token always be the same for a given user? Is it normally stored in DB or in the browser cache? Also how come I don't have to deal with the access token when using the SDK?

Comment: No, it won’t be. Client-site acquired access tokens are valid for about 2 hours only. And yes, it’s stored client-side in cookies. And you don’t have to deal with it when using built-in `FB.login` for authentication, because that takes care of setting the appropriate cookies and script-internal values.

Comment: But it might also be possible that the SDK already takes care of grabbing the access token from the hash part of the redirect URL of the login-without-the-SDK-flow itself – I have never used this method when doing client-side login, so you might just try it and tell us about the results.

Answer (score 3):

login with [facebook-javascript-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk) always opens up in popup atleast for me. if you want to it to display in complete page instead of popup you should consider other options like server side authentication where setting the option `display:page` works.

Comment: Hi Smita I am using javascript sdk and Its open Popup window for authentication. is there any option available for prevent popup and open page insted of it or any another option. You help appreciate me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: using the parameter display:page should do it though last I had tried didn't worked for me while using JavaScript SDK. For server side authentication, display:page works as expected. checkout this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ .it may help.

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers on this post worked for me: [Facebook login without pop-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125320/facebook-login-without-pop-up)

Here is the code. It should be run after `window.onload`

```
var APPID = "YOUR_APP_ID"
var uri = encodeURI('http://example.com');

FB.init({ appId: APP_ID,
          status: true, // check login status
       });
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //user is logged in
    } else {
        window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + APPID + "&redirect_uri="+uri+"&response_type=token");
    }
});
```

For complete-ness sake, here is the code that loads the FB JS SDK.

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
```

Comment: Hi posit your answer not worked for me can you please post all code here with javascript SDK which work without open popup for facebook sdk?. Your help appreciate me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added some detail, but really I can't help you unless you give a better description of the problem you're having.