# Facebook login without javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

i have a page tab where users press like and then using the js sdk i ask to grant the app for some permissions..
in order this to work on mobile devices since page-tab are not available, i have used mobile-detect..

the problem is that i don't want at mobile version the js popup but the native login window..
this can happen using the login without javascript 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/#confirm
the problem is that i m completely lost, at the redirect after the login..

```
 header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? client_id=487296798007389&redirect_uri=URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO/success.php&scope=email,friends_l ikes&response_type=token");
```

if i use the response_type code i get a code from which i can't get access token..
if i use the response_type token i get a access token with a hash tag on top and i don't know at all how to handle this..
can someone give me some quite lines on how should this be treated in order to retrieve userid

do i need to set my app to sth else apart from only page tab? since the mobile version will be accessible from my own domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found these two very usefull

with this i do a php login that it server me better in a specific occassion than js..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/

and this

[Facebook login without pop-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125320/facebook-login-without-pop-up)

it let me use js, but instead of login (that would pop up on mobile) i could use the redirect link and have similar result..

however, i noticed a case in which on some devices the second case ended in infinite loops without obvious reason