# JavaScript SDK:: FB.ui() and Popup block on mobile Safari of iOS and Android browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Now I'm implementing Facebook credit function with JavaScript SDK.
I have been using "FB.ui({method: 'pay', ....}, callback)" and now it works fine.

When I use this FB.ui function with method: 'pay' on mobile site like iPhone or Android, it try to open a another popup window for payment dialog.

But as everybody knows, iPhone or Android browser blocks popup window in default, so we must turn off popup block in settings if we want to work this FB.ui pay method.

Are there any ways not to open another popup window for the payment dialog?

Answer (score 9):

the solution is put the code that call FB.ui in the onclick attribute of the button. like the facebook web app hackbook does:

http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/ (open this in a popup window blocked browser, and click the "Prompt to Pay" in the Credits page)

here is the html code of the "Prompt to Pay" button:

```
<div id="publish_button" class="button" onclick="sendPay()">Prompt to Pay</div>
```

and here is the reason why browser doesnt block this kind of popup windows:

[Prevent pop-ups from being blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956359/stop-the-facebook-popup-blocker)

Comment: this answer is underrated